# What is the correct way to show/hide a UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I have an iPhone application that uses a UIScrollView to display a larger version of an image on the main screen. I am using IB to create the main screen that has text, small images, and price about a product. I have it setup to show/hide the UIScrollView if the user touches the small images. It works ok, but things are pretty messing in the IB layout. I have to put the UIScrollView over top of everything else and make it hidden by default. What I'd like to know is if there is a better way to accomplish this. Can I create a new nib and load the scroll view in it and load that nib when the users touches the small image? Should I construct the scroll view in my code and not use IB? Any input is appreciated!

Sorry if this is a newb question. I'm still learning.

Comment: I tried creating a new nib and putting my scrollview in there. I use this code to view the new nib file...
- (IBAction)showBigImageView {
 NSArray* nibViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LargeImage" owner:self options:nil];

 [self.view addSubview:[nibViews lastObject]];
}

It shows the new view just fine, except it doesn't show the image in the scroll view. I set the owner as my view controller and can link the scroll view object to the one I setup in the code. Any idea what is going wrong? Do I have to set the owner to something else or setup my delegate in the nib?

Answer (score 0):

Set scrollView.hidden = YES and then when tapped, set it to NO.

Comment: It's not working for me. I noticed that in viewDidLoad method this property worked correctly, but in Button's selector it's ignoring this property.